# Can you resize column widths in a google chart table?

Tags: google-visualization

So I have a table that shows the index number of the rows.  I've maximized the width of the table to be the exact same as the page.  Unfortunately the column with the index numbers are now annoying wide so I'm wondering if there's a way I can either set a cap how wide the first column is or make all the columns in the table adjustable?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Setting column widths in the Google Visualization API Tables is really annoying.  HTML tables set the column widths based on the first row of data in the table, which for the Google Visualization API is the header row (normal table construction would put the header row in `<thead>` with `<th>` tags, but Google puts it in `<tbody>` with `<td>` tags, which is why it defines the column widths).  The API does not provide any method to assign css or classes to the individual cells in the header row, so you have to write javascript to parse your table and set appropriate classes/CSS to handle your column widths.  Furthermore, since the table gets deleted from the HTML and redrawn whenever the user clicks column headers to sort the table or clicks the page buttons (if paging is enabled), you have to re-assign classes/CSS to the cells whenever the table is redrawn.  To complicate things even more, if you have a height assigned to the table so that the table will scroll when it gets too big, the API actually draws two tables in order to create the fixed header effect.

Normally I'm an advocate of using the Google Visualization API, but in the case of the Table visualization, it is sometimes more trouble than it is worth.  You might have an easier time working with another library, or creating your own custom table visualization.

If you want to continue using the Table visualization, here's some code to get you started:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {
    var headerCells = document.querySelectorAll('#myTableDiv table tr:first-child td');
    for (var i = 0; i < headerCells.length; i++) {
        // access the header cell element with headerCells.item(i)
    }
});
```